# 'SystemChrome' not defined in Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, statusbar

I am new to Flutter and I wanted to change the Status Bar color of my app. After some googling, I found a way to do so. It was to add the following code in my `main` function.

```dart
SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(SystemUiOverlayStyle(
  statusBarColor: Colors.white
));
```

But after adding it and running my app I got the following error:-

```
Compiler message:                                                       
lib/main.dart:15:40: Error: Method not found: 'SystemUiOverlayStyle'.   
  SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(SystemUiOverlayStyle(            
                                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^             
lib/main.dart:15:3: Error: Getter not found: 'SystemChrome'.            
  SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(SystemUiOverlayStyle(            
  ^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Please tell me what is the problem.
Thanks in advance!

---

My `main` function:-

```dart
void main() {
  SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(SystemUiOverlayStyle(
    statusBarColor: Colors.white
  ));
  runApp(WilliamClient());
}
```

---

My `pubspec.yaml` file:-

```
name: william_client
description: Client App for William Assistant and TV.
version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.1.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  firebase_auth: 0.8.4+5
  cloud_firestore: 0.10.1
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.2

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter

flutter:

  fonts:
    - family: Montserrat
      fonts:
        - asset: fonts/Montserrat.ttf
    - family: MontserratLight
      fonts:
        - asset: fonts/Montserrat-Light.ttf
    - family: RobotoMono
      fonts:
        - asset: fonts/RobotoMono.ttf
```

Comment: import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

Comment: It worked! Thanks for the solution. You may add it as an answer so that I can close this question.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

you should add

```
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
```